# Inserting HTML5 time into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a value that is in HTML5 time format into my database (MYSQL).  I get the message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':40 pm)' at line 3"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

  $time = $_POST['time'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO case (time) VALUES ($time)";

}
```

The time is supposed to be 2:40 PM.

Comment: is it a string? does a string need to be quoted? yes, yes it is\does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the POST data that you are sending is a string, so you need to quot it or escape it, the next is just one way to do it. Hope it helps.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO case (time) VALUES ('".$time."')";
```

Comment: `'$time'` would be sufficient and less confusing. you should also explain the answer, not just dump code

Comment: " quot it or escape it" no its AND not or.

Comment: @smith you really need to chill out

Comment: Man he is learning, that type of code is not for an app that can be hacked if you put that code on your app you really need to learn to code. With that code on an productive app obviously he will get hacked.